# Code returns undefined instead of return value

Tags: javascript, string, function

I have string  101000 or 1010100 in which I am trying to replace 100 recursively using function remove data. The function removedata should return "yes" when string is empty and "no" when string is not empty while replacing it with value 100.

It works fine for string 1010100. It returns "no" but not for string 101000 where it becomes empty.

```js
console.log(removedata("1010100"));
console.log(removedata("101000"));

function removedata(data) {
  data = data.replace("100", "");
  if (data.length == 0) {
    return "yes";
  } else {
    if (data.indexOf("100") > -1 && data.length > 0) {
      removedata(data);
    } else {
      return "no";
    }
  }
}
```

when 1010100 it returns no but
when 101000 it returns undefined

Comment: so you want to remove all occurrences of '100' like: 100a100b1001c should become ab1c ?

Comment: `removedata(data)` should be `return removedata(data)`

Comment: wouldn't regex greatly simplify this? `data = data.replace(/100/g, "");`

Comment: @AnduAndrici `"101000".replace(/100/g, "") == "100"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return` the recursive call:

```js
console.log(removedata("1010100"));
console.log(removedata("101000"));

function removedata(data) {
  data = data.replace("100", "");
  if (data.length == 0) {
    return "yes";
  } else {
    if (data.indexOf("100") > -1 && data.length > 0) {
      return removedata(data);
    } else {
      return "no";
    }
  }
}
```

Now it returns `yes` for the second one because all of the `100`s have been removed and the string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removedata(data) {
  data = data.replace("100", "");
  if (data.length == 0) {
    return "yes";
  } else {
    if (data.indexOf("100") > -1 && data.length > 0) {
      removedata(data);                                     // This branch does not return anything
    } else {
      return "no";
    }
  }
}
```